# Wrong publishing rate using ros::Rate

Tags: ros, rate, ros-fuerte, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I was trying to use ros::Rate to control the publishing rate. However for some reason, the publishing rate obtained is not the one I expected.

Here's my code:

```
ros::Publisher pub1,pub2;
ros::Rate *r1,*r2; 

void callbackInt(const std_msgs::Int16ConstPtr& msg) {
    pub1.publish(msg);
    r1->sleep();
} 

void callbackString(const std_msgs::StringConstPtr& msg) {
    pub2.publish(msg);
    r2->sleep();
} 

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    
    ros::init (argc, argv, "test");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe ("/int", 1, callbackInt );
    pub1 = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Int16> ("/pubInt", 1);

    ros::Subscriber sub2 = nh.subscribe ("/string", 1, callbackString );
    pub2 = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String> ("/pubString", 1);

    ros::Rate rate(5);
    r1 = &rate;
    ros::Rate rate2(5);
    r2 = &rate2;

    ros::spin();
}
```

The code should be pretty straightforward: basically I'm subscribing to two different topics (`/int` and `/string`) and re-publishing on different topics (`/pubInt` and `/pubString`) at different 5 hz (their original rate was different).

However, if I try to check the actual rate with `rostopic hz` I get 5 hz for `/pubInt` but half the rate (2.5) for `/pubString`. Any suggestion? Am I doing something wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48679/wrong-publishing-rate-using-ros::rate/) by [Saphrosit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2516/saphrosit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 197 on 2012-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not sleep in subscriber callbacks. The sleeps will block all other callbacks if you have just one spin thread. And I guess that's exactly what's happening. What probably happens is the following:

1. callbackInt is executed and sleeps for 5 secs.
2. callbackString is executed and doesn't sleep at all (the 5 secs are over already).
3. callbackString might be executed again depending on the implementation of spin, It publishes again and sleeps 5 seconds.

That means withing 5 seconds, you get two messages re-published for the string which would explain the rate of 2.5Hz.

Instead of sleeping in the callbacks, implement your re-publisher differently.  The simplest solution would be to re-publish in a main loop if enough time since the last publish call passed. Don't forget to call spinOnce in your main loop to execute the subscriber callbacks.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Saphrosit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2516/saphrosit/) on 2012-11-20**:
Thanks, this was actually the issue! Actually I solved using a `ros::MultiThreadedSpinner` and calling `spinner.spin()` instead of ``ros::spin()` and it seems to work. Thanks for your help!

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2015-01-22**:
Hi @Lorenz, I don't get your answer. Why `callbackString is executed and doesn't sleep at all`? Does that mean when r1 sleeps, r2 will also take r1's sleep time into account? And why callbackString might be executed again?